# Inheritence - Mock Exam

Tags: java, inheritance

I have this code:

```
class A {
    protected int x;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    
    private int answer;

    public void someMethod() {
      answer = x;
      answer = this.x;
      answer = this.getX();
      answer = super.x;
      answer = super.getX();
    } 
}
```

Which of the assignment statements in `someMethod` are valid?

I'm thinking that the two 'super' lines are correct?

Comment: The scope of any exam is to test your knowledge of the topic. Asking an "urgent" or "last-minute" question on SO defiles that scope. Plus your question isn't fit for SO anyway, for many reasons. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I have done just now but I think I've messed up. Each method with the above options in is just returning 0. They do complile though which is the main thing I guess?

Comment: I know its a shocker Kocko I apologise, just clutching at straws here!

Comment: It is always 0? That is very strange, since you never set a value to `x`, there is absolutely no possible way, that `x` has its default value ...

Comment: Think I've completely messed up the test class I just made!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which of the assignment statements in `someMethod` are valid?

All of them.

`x`, `this.x` and `super.x` all point to `protected int x` in `class A` which is visible to the subclass `B`. `this.getX()` and `super.getX()` both call `public int getX()` in `class A` which is visible to the subclass `B`.

`answer`, `x` and the return value of `getX()` are all of type `int`, so the assignment is valid.

Comment: Thanks :) Just tried it myself on a dodgy compiler and it returned 0 for all my methods so all work like you say! Cheers again.